# Plot a graph in kibana 4 with raw performance counter data

Tags: graph, aggregation, performancecounter, kibana-4, date-histogram

I am new to Kibana. Currently using version 4.1.0.

I am using logstash agent on my application servers to publish my custom performance counters to elasticsearch incidence.

The performance counter data’s are fetched from each server using logstash WMI input plugin and the interval is set to 30 seconds.

Every 30 seconds I will have a new row in elasticsearch with TimeStamp, Cumulative Calls, Calls per second, Cumulative Exceptions, Cumulative Process Success and Successful process per second.

Now my requirement is to plot a graph very similar to perfmon on the incoming performance counter data.

I tried using Kibana line chart for this requirement with TimeStamp (Date Histogram) in X axis and other counters as Y axis. But I am not sure which aggregation I need to select for each counters on Y-axis because I need to plot the graph on the raw data received and not on the calculated data.

If I select any of the aggregation then Kibana does some calculation on the data based on the selected aggregation and the result is not matching with perfmon.

Can someone point me to the right chart type and way to plot this graph in Kibana with raw value of the counter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With the x-axis as a date histogram, you'll end up with a bunch of buckets, say one per minute.  By default, the y-axis will be the count of the number of documents in that minute.

More interesting to you, perhaps, would be to change the y-axis to be the `sum` of the `Cumulative Calls` field, which would show you how many calls there had been in that minute.

To compare with other tools, make sure you're computing the same values and that your x-axis has the same scale.

Comment: Wouldn't that plot totally wrong values?  For instance, if there were 4 documents that have a counter (not a gauge) with values of 10, 12, 15, and 17, it would plot a y value of 10+12+15+17, not what it should (7, plus whatever the entry just before 10 had included)